# Mysql > Editing values of all cells in a column

Tags: php, mysql

I have this column with paragraphs of text in each cells. Since I learned last time that I can just echo the paragraph without using break tags `<br>` using the php command nl2br($string), I want to edit the cells and remove any `<br>` tags inside the values when they are present on each cell.

But doing it manually would take a long time since there are around a thousand of rows. I am wondering how to have it done in a command in mysql if it's possible. I'm logging the mysql database using the command line/SSH.

Update: here's a screenshot I have after accessing it with mysql.
[image]

The dsc column of this db table has some `<br>` tags inside its values. I want to filter them out and delete them for all the cells in the dsc column using a command/query on ssh instead of phpmyadmin (for further learning ssh stuffs).

Comment: You should define a sql update statement that matches the cells in question by means of mysqls string functions. For that you have to precisely define what you actually mean by "any tags" above.

Comment: What I wanted to know is a command/query to filter/delete certain values using ssh access on mysql database. In my issue, I want to just delete any existing <br> tags in the cells under the dsc column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will delete all br-tags in column dsc:

```
update tableName set dsc = replace(dsc,'<br>','');
```

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. Thanks for the link too, I'm gonna read it for further references.